# How can I add a constraint to my sequelize model that needs to match an existing table from my postrgres database?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to add a constraint to my banks model definition which matches my postrgres table definition.

I have tried using queryInterface to do this but i'm having a queryInterface not defined error.

Here is my banks model definition:

```
const Banks = db.define('banks', {
    bank_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    floor_number: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    bank_col_num: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    bank_row_num: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    bank_orientation: {
        type:Sequelize.CHAR
    }

}).then(
     queryInterface.addConstraint('Banks', ['bank_orientation'], {
        type: 'check',
        where: {
             bank_orientation: ['horizontal', 'vertical']
        }
    })
)
```

Here is my banks sql model definition:

```
CREATE TABLE banks (
    id SERIAL,
    bank_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    floor_number VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    bank_col_num INTEGER NOT NULL,
    bank_row_num INTEGER NOT NULL,
    bank_orientation CHAR NOT NULL CHECK (bank_orientation IN ('horizontal', 'vertical')),

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I'm hoping the model can access my postgres table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested the below but I reformatted the `.then` statement. I also added a `db` before `queryInterface` as (`queryInterface`) is not defined anywhere else in your example.

```
const Banks = db.define('banks', {
    bank_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    floor_number: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    bank_col_num: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    bank_row_num: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    bank_orientation: {
        type:Sequelize.CHAR
    }

}).then(() => {
    return db.queryInterface.addConstraint('Banks', ['bank_orientation'], {
        type: 'check',
        where: {
             bank_orientation: ['horizontal', 'vertical']
        }
    })
})
```